# What is the partial derivative for z = f(η), where η=g(x,y).

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For solving the partial derivative, I can find the example for $z = f(x,y),\; x = g(t)$, and $y=h(t)$. Also the case for $z = f(x,y),\; x = g(s,t)$, and $y=h(s,t)$ from internet.

However I cannot find the example case for  $z = f(\eta)$, where $\eta=g(x,y).$

For this case, does the partial derivative respect to $x$ or $y$ is just

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{d f}{d \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} $$

Also, can I solve $\frac{dz}{dx}$ for this cases? or they are essentially same?

Comment: In this case, $z = f(g(x,y))$, so isn't the answer just $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f'(g(x,y)) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$?  And this is essentially what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, then there is no $\frac{dz}{dx}$, only $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$.  Your formula for the partial derivative is correct.
There is also a general form of the chain rule for a function of n variables each of which is a function of m variables.